# Rails+Builder.Generate XML output without entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, character-encoding, builder

How to make Builder to not encode 'śćż' and other such characters.
What I want is 'całość' to be literally printed in XML document.
Example:

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => '1.0', :encoding => 'utf-8'
xml.Trader( :'xmlns:xsi' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
            :'xmlns:xsd' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") do
  xml.Informacje do
    xml.RodzajPaczki 'całość'
    xml.Program 'mine'
    xml.WersjaProgramu '1.0'
  end
end
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Trader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
 <Informacje>  
  <RodzajPaczki>ca&#322;o&#347;&#263;</RodzajPaczki> 
    <Program>mine</Program> 
    <WersjaProgramu>1.0</WersjaProgramu> 
  </Informacje>
</Trader>
```

`ca&#322;o&#347;&#263;` should be `całość`.
I saw pseudo solution like `xml.RodzajPaczki {|t| t << 'całość' }` but it does not work correctly. It outdent 'całość' to left side of a document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what is happening. As we know by default Builder will escape non ASCII characters like the ones in `całość`. You've also mentioned one possible way to kinda fix it and that is:

```
xml.RodzajPaczki {|t| t << 'całość' }
```

Unfortunately when you pass a block to the `RodzajPaczki` element, Builder assumes that there will be some inner xml, so it adds a new line and applies the indent. Of course in our case there is only inner text and no xml so we get some unsightly output like:

```
<RodzajPaczki>
całość      </RodzajPaczki>
```

There is an easy way and a harder way to fix this. First the easy way.

**Configure Indent To Be Zero**

Then you can use the fix from above `xml.RodzajPaczki {|t| t << 'całość' }` everything will work as expected, but the output will not be pretty printed, it will infact be all on one line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Trader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Informacje><RodzajPaczki>całość</RodzajPaczki><Program>mine</Program><WersjaProgramu>1.0</WersjaProgramu></Informacje></Trader>
```

You can run this through an external pretty printer if you want it nicely formatted.

If you simply must have pretty printed output and want no escaping, we need to patch Builder slightly. This is the harder way to fix this issue.

**Patching Builder**

We need to patch the initializer of our `XmlMarkup` object to add an extra option `:escape`. At the same time we patch the `XmlBase` object to take this new option as a parameter. We default this new option to `true`, to maintain the default behaviour. We then patch the `text!` method on `XmlBase` to use our new option to decide if we should escape text of not. Here is what it looks like:

```
module Builder
  class XmlBase
    def initialize(indent=0, initial=0, encoding='utf-8', escape=true)
      @indent = indent
      @level  = initial
      @encoding = encoding.downcase
      @escape = escape
    end

    def text!(text)
      if @escape
        _text(_escape(text))
      else
        _text(text)
      end
    end
  end

  class XmlMarkup
    def initialize(options={})
      indent = options[:indent] || 0
      margin = options[:margin] || 0
      encoding = options[:encoding] || 'utf-8'
      escape = options[:escape]
      if escape == nil
        escape = true
      end
      super(indent, margin, encoding, escape)
      @target = options[:target] || ""
    end
  end
end
```

We can now use our newly patched builder in the following way (***notice that when we construct the `XmlMarkup` object we pass in our new `:escape` options with a value of `false`***):

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=>STDOUT, :indent=>3, :encoding => 'utf-8', :escape => false)
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => '1.0', :encoding => 'UTF-8'
xml.Trader(:'xmlns:xsi' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", :'xmlns:xsd' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") do 
  xml.Informacje do
    xml.RodzajPaczki('całość')
    xml.Program('mine')
    xml.WersjaProgramu('1.0')
  end
end
```

The output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Trader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Informacje>
      <RodzajPaczki>całość</RodzajPaczki>
      <Program>mine</Program>
      <WersjaProgramu>1.0</WersjaProgramu>
   </Informacje>
</Trader>
```

As desired the text is not escaped. Note that the patch will apply this non-escaping behaviour to all text, so if you only want some of the text to be non-escaped while other text is still escaped you'll need to patch Builder to a much greater extent.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. Very informative answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to configure indent to be zero if I am using the xml builder object in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this using my setup.  What version of ruby/ rails/ builder are you using?

Comment: Ruby version 1.8.7 Enterprise Edition, Rails 2.3.5, builder 2.1 but I'm not 100% sure. I mean I am out of work now and I have several projects in rails to maintain.

Comment: Ok. I easily replicated the same behaviour with rails 3.0.9 ruby 1.9.2 and builder 3.0.0 on my private machine. So is there a way in Builder to output 'całość' literaly, not `ca&#322;o&#347;&#263;` ?

Answer (score 0):

I can output "całość" without problems (Ruby 1.9.2, Builder 3.0.0).
The manual page http://builder.rubyforge.org/ suggests to set `$KCODE` to `'UTF8'` (see the very end of the page), but i think this is for Ruby 1.8.
What i have in my file, is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -wE UTF-8:UTF-8
# encoding: UTF-8

require 'builder'
...

xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new( :target => target, :indent => 2 )
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => '1.0', :encoding => 'UTF-8'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment in [Rails ticket #1446](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1446-fix-utf-8-output-for-builder#ticket-1446-6) indicates that this may be fixed in Builder 3.0.0. I haven't tried it yet myself however.